# Dockerfile - deploy mysql dump in entrypoint

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to connect to external container in entrypoint and upload DB dump to it?

I always get **web_1 exited with code 0** on this line execution: *mysql -h$MYSQL_HOST -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD $MYSQL_DATABASE < magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0/magento_sample_data_for_1.9.1.0.sql* in install-sampledata from Dockerfile

However, I can do *docker exec -it <> bash* after containers creation, execute install-sampledata there and it works

I have such docker-compose

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6.23
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql/data
    env_file:
      - env
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8089:80"
    links:
      - db
    env_file:
      - env
    tty: true
volumes:
  db-data:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM alexcheng/magento

ENTRYPOINT install-sampledata
```

and install-sampledata file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd /tmp
cp /opt/magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tgz .
tar xvf magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0.tgz
cp -R magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0/media/* /var/www/htdocs/media/
cp -R magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0/skin/* /var/www/htdocs/skin/
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/htdocs/media

mysql -h$MYSQL_HOST -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD $MYSQL_DATABASE < magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0/magento_sample_data_for_1.9.1.0.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: your `ENTRYPOINT` is `install-sampledata`: a script which will run one mysql command and... exit!
At this point the container will stop.

If possible, it is best to call that script, and then [call mysql as in the mysql Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/6c414e7f38c2079c7193beae5dc7c34ee46cd6e7/8.0/Dockerfile#L70), in order to leave a foreground process running.

Or you can have a look at [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/), in order to build an image with your pre-requisite files already baked in.

---

Comment: Why container web stops? As I can understand, mysql is working on db container. Web container connects to it using mysql -h db .. and uploads dump. And that's all. So, why web container stops after?

Comment: @freento The all idea behind a container lifecycle is that it runs as long as its main process runs. In yor case, your main process is a simple command. Once that command completes, it stops.

Answer (score 0):

You have an entry point in mysql containers that allows you to have the container use your mysql dump upon startup.  Make a volume to here /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d and you're container will populate your database.

Answer (score 0):

Add

> sh -c /bin/bash

at last to your install-sampledata script. It will start a new process bash with a new pid. So your container will not die.